# React with Hooks: how to correctly update state after a click event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, rerender

In my JSX, I'm, mapping through an array of objects (imported from a local JS file) to display a set of icons with a key, id and alt tag.

I use hooks to set a state to an empty string. I want to use an onClick event (passed to the **HeroIcons** component) to replace this state with the id of the clicked icon (that id is a string). Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import HeroImages from "../images/HeroImages";
import HeroIcons from "../components/HeroIcons";
import HeroShowcase from "../components/HeroShowcase";

const Heroes = () => {
  const [hero, currentHero] = useState("");

  const setCurrentHero = e => {
    currentHero(e.target.id);
    console.log(hero);
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-heroes">
        <ul className="hero-list">
          {/* map function below */}
          {HeroImages.map(({ id, src, altTag }) => (
            <HeroIcons
              key={id}
              id={id}
              src={src}
              altTag={altTag}
              setCurrentHero={setCurrentHero}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="col-showcase">
        <HeroShowcase />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Heroes;
```

Inside the heroIcons component:

```
import React from "react";

const HeroIcons = props => {
  return (
    <li key={props.id} id={props.id} onClick={props.setCurrentHero}>
      <img src={props.src} alt={props.altTag} />
    </li>
  );
};

export default HeroIcons;
```

When clicking on an icon (created by the map function), the id isn't logged to the console. However, when I furiously click it many times, sometimes an id DOES get logged. This gives me a hint that this click event could be causing the map function to re-run and prevent the normal console log
[image]

How could I fix this this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you have to use `e.currentTarget.id` instead of `e.target.id` so you get the `id` of current image.

```
  const setCurrentHero = e => {
    currentHero(e.currentTarget.id);
    console.log(hero);
  };
```

**Second** `useState` Hook needs you to handle the callback to use `log` the value of the current state, while it doesn't accept the `callback` like `setState`.
You can use `useEffect` but It would better if you use the value of `e.currentTarget.id`;

Comment: thanks, using e.currentTarget.id helped to solve this issue. I'm also using your & Zohaib Ijaz's suggestion about useEffect. I'm getting the clicked hero's ID now, but I'm also looking into how to prevent this to run after the first load of the page

Comment: If I understand you right, you can also use ‘useEffect’ and pass an empty array to it to achieve the ‘componentDidMount’.

Comment: so I applied your and @ZohaibIjaz solutions combined. This is my code now 

`const [hero, currentHero] = useState("");

  const setCurrentHero = e => {
    currentHero(e.currentTarget.id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Current hero is:", hero);
  }, [hero]);` 

The console log has the "current hero is:" string (without the id) included after first loading the page. I wonder if I could log this only after triggering the click event

Comment: If i understand you, you can write it like this `if (hero) console.log("Current hero is:", hero);`

Comment: Thank you, the "if statement" helped me now achieve the desired outcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you `hero` is not updated at the time of console so you need to use `useEffect` hook when that value is updated

```js
const setCurrentHero = e => {
  currentHero(e.target.id);
  console.log(hero);
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Hero', hero);
}, [hero]);
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just set the value in the render:

```
<HeroIcons
          key={id}
          id={id}
          src={src}
          altTag={altTag}
          setCurrentHero={setCurrentHero(id)}
        />
```